# Zerobrane Corona sdk live buils debug

Tags: zerobrane

Hi again and one more question about Zerobrane, Corona and debug.
My problem now is that when I build an app with live build enabled, and when i try to run it on the device, the app halts. This is happening only when i enable the debug. Is the debug feature working only without enabling the live builds?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Corona SDK are you using? I unfortunately don't have it setup to try myself, but does the debugging start in the IDE when you run the application on the device? You can get additional debugging information by adding `debugger.verbose=true` to the config to see what is being sent and received by the debugger.

Comment: Corona Version 2017.3145, I have debugger to verbose but nothing showing. The app on the device halts immediately at the beginning.

Comment: It does look like the debugging request is not coming through. You may want to check that the debugger is started (`Project | Start Debugging Server`) and that the firewall doesn't block requests to port 8172 from non-local processes.

Comment: the debugger is started, and no problem with firewall. When it is not live builds the debugger works. When it is live build the app halts, it runs only when i remove the require('mobdebug').start("the ip address")